# Get a full list of users from LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

I try to use the code below to get the full list of user. But I get the code "The server could not be contacted."

Any idea ?

Thanks,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string groupName = "Domain Users";
    string domainName = "LDAP://ldap.mycompany.be:389/ou=users,o=mycompany,dc=mycompany,dc=be";

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

    if (grp != null)
    {
        foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", p.SamAccountName, p.DisplayName));
        }


        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Update :** This code is working (from the same machine)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string userUid = "myuser";


    DirectoryEntry Ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.mycompany.be:389/ou=users,o=mycompany,dc=mycompany,dc=be", "", "", AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
    DirectorySearcher LdapSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(Ldap, String.Format("(&(objectClass=*)(uid={0}))", userUid));


    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeNumber");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("facsimileTelephoneNumber");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("foremfunction");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("foremservice");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("foremsite");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("inetUserStatut");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");
    LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
    SearchResultCollection LdapSearcherResults = LdapSearcher.FindAll();

    foreach (SearchResult resultLdap in LdapSearcherResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(resultLdap.Properties["cn"][ 0].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(resultLdap.Properties["uid"][0].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(resultLdap.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
    }
}
```

**Update2**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
  StackTrace:
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name)
       at MoulinetteUser.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\.....\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Did you try that connection string with a LDAP tool from your developer machine?

Comment: More details please. Can you browse with LDAP tool? Any firewalls? and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your arguments for PrincipalContext are not right : you're passing in an LDAP query in domainName, instead of the name and port of your domain controller. See [MSDN for full documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb298328.aspx) on that class.

Your second code post works because the class you're using is an LDAP client class, and it "understands" your ldap query.

Try the following and see if it works :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string groupName = "Domain Users";
    string domainName = "ldap.mycompany.be"; // or whatever your domain controller's name is...

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

    if (grp != null)
    {
        foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", p.SamAccountName, p.DisplayName));
        }


        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: On the "PrincipalContext ctx" line, I get this error after few second "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Thanks for your help.

Comment: On this line : PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName); ? What's the exception trace ?

Comment: Is the machine part of the domain ?

Comment: Not in the domaine, but I think about that, my second sample is working on the same machine and a tracert to ldap.mycompany.com give me the right result.

Comment: Yes, but these two codes are really different : your second sample is only contacting the "LDAP part" of your AD. You don't need to be part of the directory to do that. The first code sample with PrincipalContext depends on the AD, and I believe (though it needs to be confirmed) requires the client machine to be part of the domain... To put it simply, you're not using LDAP to query the AD in your first sample.